# Can't ping Bonjour address can actually connect to it

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, ping, putty, bonjour

There is something weird going on on my network.

I have a raspberry running Raspbian, with name "Myraspberry" and i am trying to find the IP address from my computer running windows with Bonjour installed on it.

if i ping Myraspberry.local i get nothing, but if i open Bonjour Browser i am actually getting the IP and name correctly. I can connect via SSH with putty using that name which makes me wonder that there is something fishy going on.

So what could be the cause of not being able to ping the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO I had installed bonjour itself, by uninstalling it and installing itunes made it to work properly, might be a bug on the stand alone bonjour